# CKAN - How are Groups persisted in Postgres, I can't see parental links

Tags: ckan

I am trying to figure out how data is persisted in CKAN.  I created an Organization with 2 sub organizations (I used the Ckanext-hierarchy plug-in) but when I look in the Postgresql Database I don't see how the records are linked.

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn about [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The 'member' table stores the tree/hierarchy between organizations (which are stored as 'group's).

`model.Group.get_parent_groups` finds a group's parent in the hierarchy. It is thought of in this way: the child group is a 'member' of the parent.